# How Can I reload the umbraco installed in my visual studio solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I already have umbraco cms 7.4 in my solution. When I first run the solution it will popup the Editing page of umbraco. But when I stop the solution and run it again it reload the localhost instead of umbraco editing template. How do I get back to the editing template of umbraco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to point your browser to the /umbraco/ folder (like http://localhost/umbraco/) ?